# How to create a random matrix with all numbers in given range in every row in Python?

Tags: python, matrix

I need rows with all numbers in range (0,6), numbers can repeat, but rows must contain all of them. For example:

```
[1, 0, 4, 5, 3, 2, 2, 0]
[3, 4, 0, 0, 1, 2, 5, 4]
[0, 5, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 5]
```

I have tried with random.randint(), but some of the numbers are missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a list containing each value once, then complete it with random numbers to reach the length you want, and finally shuffle the list:

```
import random

def random_row(max_val=6, length=8):
    # we include all numbers from 0 to max_val once
    row = list(range(max_val+1))
    # we add as many random numbers as needed to complete 
    for _ in range(length - max_val - 1):
        row.append(random.randint(0, max_val))
    # and we shuffle the list
    random.shuffle(row)
    return row

for _ in range(3):
    print(random_row())
```

Output:

```
[3, 2, 0, 5, 6, 4, 4, 1]
[5, 1, 6, 0, 2, 0, 4, 3]
[5, 1, 6, 4, 2, 2, 0, 3]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
r = np.random.rand(7).argsort()
```

Comment: The rows are supposed to contain **8** numbers, with all numbers from 0 to 6 appearing at least once. This fails to satisfy the OP's expectations.